# How to add JavaScript to button where it will generate another button linking to another page?

Tags: javascript, html, button

i am trying to use JavaScript where i can click on a button and it will generate a button above it so for example i have the first button called add additional:

```
<a href"#"><button type="button">Add Additional</button></a>
```

When this button is clicked and it will generate another button where i want it to be displayed the below:

```
    <td>
         Name
   </td>
   <td>
      <a href="somewhere"><button type="button">Choose another thing</button></a>
   </td>
```

and is it possible to repeat this process like generating more of the 2nd button "Choose Another thing"

i hope this ins't too confusing

Answer (score 0):

Give an id/class for a division append to it.

```
<div id='my_id' >
  <td>Name</td>
  <td><button>click</button></td>
</div>
```

When you click on addMore button write a function to append it to my_id

```
    function onclickforaddbutton(){
        id = document.getElementById('my_id');
        var data = prompt("Enter something");  //where you can get data from user 
        id.innerHTML+="<td>"+data+"</td><td><button>Something</button></td>";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first decide (container) where to add a new row. Then on click of add button, you can create a row with two columns, for the name and the new button, and append that row as a child of the container.

Here's how you can do it.

```js
var count = 1;
var name = 'Generated Name';

function addNewRow() {
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
  newRow.innerHTML = "<td>" + name + (count++) + "</td><td><button>Choose another thing</button></td>"
  container.appendChild(newRow);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div style="padding: 2rem;">
    <table id="container">
    </table>
  </div>
  <a href="#"><button onclick="addNewRow();">Add Additional</button></a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way, to have Name and the button to be generated in the same line as well if i want to generate it, above the add addtional button do i just change the append to prepend?

Comment: Which name do you want to generate? And yes you can do this, var newButton = document.createElement('button').innerHTML= "Button "+count++;

Comment: i want it so when ever i press that button, it will generate 
Name              (newButton HERE),
ive set it up as a form with two columns first column is the name and the 2nd column is the button

Comment: @andyye, Have a look at the updated code. I hope this is what you meant!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this!! Just add a script so that whenever you click on the button it will execute it and create more buttons.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the "Add Additional" button to create a BUTTON element with a "Choose Another Thing" text.</p>

<a href="#"><button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Add Additional</button></a>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Choose another thing");
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### I think this is the elegant way.

```js
function appendButton(textContent, selector) {
  var button = document.createElement('button');
      button.classList.add('any');
      button.innerHTML = textContent;
  
  var selectedElement = document.querySelector(selector);
  
  return selectedElement.appendChild(button);
}


// Call this function from wherever u like
// appendButton('click here', '.container');
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button onclick="appendButton('click here', '.container')">
     Click me
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this you will get your solution

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function myFunction()
 {
    var a=document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href","secondpage.html");
    var btn=document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var text=document.createTextNode("Choose another thing");
    btn.appendChild(text);
    a.appendChild(btn);
    document.body.appendChild(a);
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href"#"><button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Add 
Additional</button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For this just need to understand the HTML DOM Structure and than you will understand all this.